# Windows Azure version backward

Tags: asp.net, web-services, azure

Today, I checked my windows azure website (built with a web service) And the version was not the same as yesterday. It's very strange, it seems that ther version went backward.
So I took my project in VS and reuploaded it. Then it was good

I am quite scared, is it a normal behaviour, I think not. But how to stop this behaviour. If I remember well it's not the first time it happens to my project.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the explanation of the Microsoft Support :
Any changes made with Web Deploy are temporary. It can only be used for development and testing and not intended for updating applications in production. When the role instance is restarted, the changes will be gone. We would suggest that you upgrade the deployment by uploading package files from the management portal or disabling WebDeploy while deploying.
You can read more about Web Deploy here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cloud/archive/2011/04/19/enabling-web-deploy-for-windows-azure-web-roles-with-visual-studio.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

Internally if there is any problem within Azure, It is the nature of Azure to Remove the troublesome VMs and Deploy a new VM with the "cspkg" File that we upload during application deployment either through Azure portal or through Visual studio directly.
 In case You make any changes through RDP to the deployed application, there is no guarantee that the application will retain the Changes.

Further more if you face this again, it is better to contact [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/oas/default.aspx?gprid=14928&st=1&wfxredirect=1&sd=gn&ln=en-us), They should help you out.

Comment: I think you're right, the best solution is to contact directly the Microsoft Support to have further information.